# I'm looking for a word that means the area a person last slept

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a word that means the area or location a person last slept at or something close to that. The part of speech doesn't matter to me. Possible sentences may look like:

P1: "Where did you last sleep?"

P2: "My _ was at my desk in class."

Comment: You should include a sample sentence to show how the word would be used.

Comment: Is slang acceptable? A particular dialect/region of English? What are your criteria for accepting a word? Please help others in the community to give you **just the right word.**

Comment: [_spawn point_](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190251/if-the-bed-you-last-slept-in-is-destroyed-or-mined-where-do-you-respawn-when-yo). Jokes aside, you could rephrase to "Where did you last sleep?"

Comment: Slang is acceptable as long as anyone can understand it and its not specific to an isolated area.